# javascript avoid duplicate URLs

Tags: javascript, string, url, url-rewriting, uri

How can I check if two URLs are the same in javascript?

For example I wouldn't want to store both of these in a database:

> [example.com/dogs/](http://example.com/dogs/)
>   [example.com/dogs](http://example.com/dogs)

or both of these:

> [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
>   [example.com](http://example.com)

or both of these:

> http://example.com
>   https://example.com

...and what about GET data in URLs? My database could get really messy.

Is there a way I can convert all of the URLs into some standard form so that checking for duplicates would be much simpler?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: None of those are really the same. Are those the only differences that you want merged?

Comment: It is not always true that content on `http://example.com` is the same as on `https://example.com`. Same for your other examples. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Are you planning on using JS to access a database?...

Comment: Doesn't [google](http://google.com) do something like this? They don't have duplicate urls in their search results. Or do they check the contents of the page and make sure they're the same, before declaring them duplicate URLs?

Comment: @cambraca I'm using [HTML5 localstorage](http://html5doctor.com/storing-data-the-simple-html5-way-and-a-few-tricks-you-might-not-have-known)

Comment: @Phrogz In some cases it would be helpful to remove the query portion of a URL: `products.com/?clickid=123` (or else the database will get messy) ...but in some cases it would be dangerous if removed: `blog.com/?postid=123` ...so I'm not really sure what to do about the query portion. Best leave em?

Answer (score 0):

Google solved this problem by usign [link rel="canonical"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) - this proces is called [canonicalization](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066).

Of course you can simplify urls with regexp as you describe, but "example.com" and "www.example.com" could be different sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store the based domain for a site this is what I would do.

```
var url = "http://www.xyzsite.com/mySite/?param=1"; // This is the url you want to process.

var filter = [
    "http://",
    "https://",
    "www.",
];

// Loops through array and removes the protocol and www. prefixes if present
for (var i in filter) {
    url = url.replace(filter[i], "");
}

// Returns everything before the first / in the URL
var cleanUrl = url.split("/")[0]; // cleanUrl should equal "xyzsite.com" now
```

I would probably wrap it in a function so that it would be easy to run multiple times too.

Comment: I want subfolder & subdomains to work aswell. Your method would turn both `example.com/dogs` and `example.com/cats` into `example.com`. That's not really what i'm looking for.

Comment: This would work for subdomains but not subfolders. If you want to support subfolders just don't do the .split("/")[0] part.